# How to check for plain text response from a POST request?

Tags: node.js, web-api-testing, frisby.js

I'm trying to use frisby.js to specify an API test for an endpoint that returns a plain text response to a valid POST request.  However I'm having problems getting frysby.js to accept non-JSON response documents.  Whenever a response returns non-JSON content, throw a `TypeError` due to `'Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0'`.

As an example, I'm sending a HTTP POST request with the JSON document shown below is expected to return a response with a plaintext document with the string `bar`.

```js
{
    "foo":{
        "name":"bar"
    }
}
```

Here's the unit test that I've wrote to verify the response:

```js
it('should create a foo resource', function () {
  return frisby.post('http://localhost:8080/', 
      {
        "foo":{
          "name":"bar"
        }
      })
    .expect('status',201);
});
```

Unfortunately, the following error is thrown by frisby.js when I run the test:

> FAIL  ./test.js
>    ✕ should create a foo resource (17ms)
>
> ● should create a foo resource
>
> TypeError: Invalid json response body: 'bar' at http://localhost:8080/ reason: 'Unexpected token b in JSON at position 0'

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure each test to expect some data format other than JSON?

Comment: the response you checking is in JSON format or in plain text

Answer (score 0):

If you getting `JSON` + something then break `jsonTypes` in two format like one for `JSON` object and one for other, like it having array in `JSON` objects. 
and then put expect conditions on them.

This might helps you:

```
const frisby = require('frisby');
const Joi = frisby.Joi;

frisby.globalSetup({
    headers : {
        "Accept": "application/json", 
        "content-type" : "application/json",
    }
});

it("should create a foo resource", function () {
    frisby.post("http://localhost:8080/")
        .expect("status", 200)
        .expect("header", "content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        .expect("jsonTypes", "data.foo", {
            "name": Joi.string()
        })
        .then(function(res) { // res = FrisbyResponse object
            var body = res.body;
            body = JSON.parse(body);

            expect(body.data.foo.name).toBeDefined();
        })
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the API returns a single text string.  Do you happen to know if frisby.js allows users to access the raw HTTP response without calling any deserializer?

Comment: I never used without calling any deserializer. But why you doing so.

Comment: I need to test an API that returns plaintext response bodies, and apparently Frisby throws errors on any non-JSON response.

Comment: please see this once: https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/issues/419#issuecomment-347315832

Comment: REST API clients don't expect JSON.  Clients specify the desired output types through the `Accept` header.  That comment only mentions that clients expect valid JSON but only when the client expects JSON.  In my example the client expects plaintext, and it would be nice if it was possible to configure a test to expect plaintext or run tests on raw response data.  If a client expects plaintest it makes no sense for the test to fail because the response can't be converted to valid JSON.

Comment: frisby.globalSetup({
    headers : {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain", 
        "content-type" : "application/json",
    }
});